# Cannot run method one after another

Tags: jquery, cordova

```
          function retrieve_Data() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.1.186/json_android/getItemData.php",
            jsonpCallback: 'item',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var markup = "";
                $.each(data.list, function(i, elem) {
                    dbInsert(elem['itemCode'], elem['description'], elem['price']);
                });
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            },
            error: function(request, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }


function dbInsert(itemCode, description, price) {

    var sqlTxt = "INSERT INTO ITEMS (itemCode,description,price ) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [itemCode, description, price]);
            }, errorCB);
}


    function queryDB(callback) {
        var sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS";
        db.transaction(
                function(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(sqlTxt, [],
                            function(tx, results) {
                                console.log("Length is" + results.rows.length);
                                var item_Codes = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                                    item_Codes.push({item_code: results.rows.item(i).itemCode, description: results.rows.item(i).description, price: results.rows.item(i).price});
                                }
                                callback(item_Codes);
                            })
                            , errorCB;
                });
        return false;
    }
```

I have 3 methods in my jquery file.retrieve,insert and querydb.Each functions work perfectly.Once the retrieve function calls it takes the data from server and save inide a database.When the querydb is  run it take all the value from db and save inside a array.When i run each method separately it works fine.but i need run after another these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Your all methods are fine that is why they run perfectly when you execute them seperately.

The Problem is in ajax call actually, when you call a Webservice through ajax the control goes outside to the function before ajax gives the response. So When you call retrieve_Data() method, it calls a webservice through ajax and before it get the response your function retrieve_Data has been ends that is why dbInsert method not called, result you can't get the result as you want.

Now the time for solution, You Should use setTimeout method. It will wait for 5000 milliseconds after that your method will ends.

```
function retrieve_Data() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.1.186/json_android/getItemData.php",
            jsonpCallback: 'item',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var markup = "";
            $.each(data.list, function(i, elem) {
                dbInsert(elem['itemCode'], elem['description'], elem['price']);
            });
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
         console.log("Wait for Webservice Response");
    },5000);
}
```

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Actually if i run retrieve data it runs perfectly and data will be saved.Because i run insert data inside the sucsess function.It is but i cannot retrieve the data using queryDB.